# Grails firing find and save query when performing domain.save()

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, dns, grails3

I have a piece of code in Grails2x  with sql database. I have a table which is mapped to a domain. It was working fine with grails2x but as I update it to *grails 3.2.9* ,  when I perform *domain.save()* it fires find query in hibernate and then update query and finally it fails.

Below I've attached error log:

> org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

One more thing I will like to add for those table whose data type is varchar, domain.save() is working fine, but the table with column nvarchar type is giving above error. Can somebody explain me the cause and its expected solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing  *generator: 'assigned'* in different mapped primary key while defining mapping for id.